# Lotusscript - Type mismatch when useing ArrayGetIndex

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

**I have a function where I check if a string is found in a variant:**

```
Function checkIfValueIsInVariant (tempVariant As Variant, tempValue As String) As Boolean
    Dim valueFound As Boolean

    'zet standaard waarde op niet gevonden
    valueFound = False
    Print "Value : " + tempValue
    If Not IsNull( ArrayGetIndex(tempVariant, tempValue) ) Then
            'waarde is gevonden in variant dus zet op true
            valueFound = true
    End If
        checkIfValueIsInVariant = valueFound
End Function
```

When I go through the code with the debugger then I can see these values:

```
tempVariant = "value" type = Variant
tempValue = "value" type = String
```

But when it is executing this line:

```
`If Not IsNull( ArrayGetIndex(tempVariant, tempValue) )` Then
```

I get Type mismatch, What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variant is a very bad data type in LotusScript: it can contain anything. ArrayGetIndex expects the first parameter to be `An array or Variant containing an array.`. In your example tempvariant is a Variant of type string and NOT an array --> Type mismatch.

If I don't know, if I get a scalar or an array in before then usually I write something like that in my code:

```
Dim varArray as Variant
Dim arrOneElement(0) as Variant


If not IsArray( tempVariant ) then
    arrOneElement(0) = tempVariant
    varArray = arrOneElement
Else
    varArray = tempVariant 
End If
If Not IsNull( ArrayGetIndex(varArray, tempValue) ) Then
```

That way I can put in there (almost) whatever I want and it will return the correct result.